# How to sendmail via command line piping

Tags: linux, sendmail

I have a cron command that runs a file and I'm trying to setup the output so it emails to me. I use this with 3rd party scripts that I don't want to modify the direct files, so I need to pipe the output instead of modifying the PHP.

I'm migrating from a server that uses `mail` to a server that uses `sendmail`.  I'm struggling to find out how to properly send a subject to sendmail via a command line.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /path/to/file.php 2>&1 | /usr/sbin/sendmail -s "My Test Email Subject" test@email.com
```

Comment: `sendmail` is the binary that is used by your system to route mail that  is submitted to it by `mail`. It is part of a suite of programs like _[sendmail](http://www.sendmail.org)_, _postfix_, _exim_ and so on. So you need to install the appropriate package for [mail](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail). So tell us the linux distribution that you are using.

Comment: All POSIX compliant forms of UNIX/Linux should provide some executable named "sendmail" and taking a specific set of options which are compatible with a subset of sendmail's functionality (including the -t option, described in timday's answer, below).  Exim, Postfix, and qmail all provide these --- sometimes they'll be installed under /usr/libexec/sendmail rather than /usr/bin or /usr/sbin, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> /usr/sbin/sendmail

That's wrong.

You should have a `mail` command some where. It could be called `mailx`. Should be in the `/bin/` directory. As standard practice, php scripts should never be calling anything in `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`. The sbin programs are typically for root.

Also, php has a built in [mail function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: If it is not `mail` or `mailx` it may be `Mail`. But even if those do not exist, you can install [mutt](http://www.mutt.org) and run `mutt -x` which emulates `mailx`.

Comment: This is true... to determine my path, I ran `which mail` and it returned `/bin/mail`.

Comment: sendmail is the better approach (it's a Posix standard) ... but it's better to use sendmail -t (take the headers from the input stream).  This avoids many possible shell variable interpolation vulnerabilities by allowing the program sending mail to interact only with the sendmail utility without invoking any shell at all).  See "timday's" answer for better details.

Answer (score 15):

On my Debian systems (which have Exim rather than "real" sendmail, but still have a sendmail binary for compatibility), when I want to send mail from a script I do something equivalent to:

```
cat <<EOF | sendmail -t
To: recipient@example.com
Subject: Testing
From: sender@example.com

This is a test message
EOF
```

Note that the blank line is important.

Comment: The blank line is used to separate the header part of a message from the message body. Why not `sendmail -t <<EOF` though?

Comment: @adamo: Because it was closer to the pattern in the original question to pipe into sendmail with '|' (and in fact the places I do this myself it's generally something like generate_test_message.sh | sendmail -t ).

Comment: This is the canonical approach to safe programmatic mail sending under UNIX.

Comment: finally got a working example for sendmail! Thank you!

Comment: if the `sendmail` were to fail and write to STDERR, how could I capture this as a variable to use later in the script?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "This is my body\nSecond line" 2>&1 | sed '1!b;s/^/To: test@email.com\nSubject: My Test Email Subject\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

echo = The body of the email.
sed stuff = Applies the email headers, and important double-line between body and headers.
sendmail -t = Pipes it directly through sendmail.

Answer (score -1):

```
php -f file.php 2>&1 | sed 's/^/To: test@email.com\nSubject: My Test Email Subject\n\n/' | sendmail -t
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Server Fault. Perhaps you could elaborate your answer a bit?